# Error MSB3073 Exited With Code 1 and unable to load the service index for source index.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, dockerfile

I've tried to build my Docker image and this is what happens when I build it. Is there any wrong setting?

```
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.100\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\src\DockNetMicro\DockNetMicro.csproj]
2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.100\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : No such host is known [C:\src\DockNetMicro\DockNetMicro.csproj]
2>The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore "DockNetMicro/DockNetMicro.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
2>C:\Users\rizka.hasmulyawan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.0.2105168\build\Container.targets(159,5): error MSB3073: The command "docker build -t "docknetmicro" -f "e:\work\note\netcoretest\docknetmicro\docknetmicro\dockerfile" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" ".."" exited with code 1.
2>Done building project "DockNetMicro.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockNetMicro/DockNetMicro.csproj", "DockNetMicro/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockNetMicro/DockNetMicro.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockNetMicro"
RUN dotnet build "DockNetMicro.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockNetMicro.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockNetMicro.dll"]
```

Comment: Please add some code so one can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've solving my problem :

download and install

https://cloudnimble.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/cloudnimble/nugetpackagereferenceupgrader/1.0.1/1508705706028/281869/2/NuGet%20PackageReference%20Upgrader%20v1.0.1.vsix

then restart the computer

thanks for helping guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known frequent bug. 
The problem you are having is that you are not able to restore packages from nuget inside your container.

I would suggest these to resolve your error:

1. using a different version of that image which might have a different version of dotnet runtime. Sometimes different versions of dotnet are able to restore packages.
2. build and publish everything in your local host system and copy that folder to your container. just use the base image as the destination. Keep the local output directory of dlls as your source.